# Get all Cities of Country from DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to get **all Cities of India** from DBpedia database.

I tried many stackoverflow solutions but till now i have not got my required output.

How to fetch all Cities of Country using SPARQL.

Comment: I tried to get Cities & Country using This Query => 
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?country 
WHERE { ?city rdf:type dbo:City ; 
  rdfs:label ?label ; 
  dbo:country ?country 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be (for sure) incomplete since data in DBpedia is based on mappings from Wikipedia (here only the infoboxes):

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?s WHERE {
 ?s a dbo:City ;
    dbo:country dbr:India
}
```

Or you can try to use the Wikipedia categories:

```sql
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {
 ?s dct:subject/skos:broader* dbc:Cities_and_towns_in_India
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me Why "Beijing" City is not showing for China Country. [ dbr:China ]  My Query => SELECT ?placeName WHERE {
 ?placeName a dbo:City ; dbo:country dbr:China
}

Comment: You can always see why if you look at the corresponding page: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Beijing . It doesn't belong to the class `dbo:City` - why, I can't say. This depends on the infobox mappings to Wikipedia

Comment: Oh!! So what could I do to Show such types of Cities.

Comment: The answer is: You don't have any guarantee that the data is complete or perfect. I mean, for Bejing you could try to find a workaround, but for others that you don't know indeed you won't recognize that those are missing. Again, a workaround is to use the Wikipedia category (my second query), i.e. `dbc:Cities_in_China`

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fetch cities from this [wikiLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Afghanistan). 
 I want all list of Cities from this  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Afghanistan) using DBpedia

Answer (score 1):

I got solution to get Cities of Country. For Example if we want to fetch cities of India then use **dbr:India** in your Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?placeName WHERE {
 ?placeName a yago:City108524735 ; dbo:country dbr:India
}
```

Thanks @AKSW for your help.